# How to check Uber Trials of Ascendancy progress?

Tags: path-of-exile

In the 3 in-game difficulties, you are able to check your progress at the plaque in Act 3, Sarn Encampment. Without doing a map run, is it possible to check your current completed trials?

Comment: Just as a comment, you will find a map trial quite fast if you spend some time on /global 820.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 3.0 there is a way to check the progress outside of maps.

Once you have activated the waypoint in Aspirants' plaza you will have a new icon on the world map:
[image]

Once in the Aspirants' plaza, the new "Labyrinth activation device" will show your current progress:

[image]

As I show in the image, by going with the mouse over one of the icons will show you which trial it refers to.

Comment: This is now the accepted answer. The QoL change was much needed and I'm glad they've added it in.

Answer (score 4):

No. It's not possible to check without finding a trial in a map. This is a pretty common complaint and will probably get addressed at some point, but not yet.

Comment: Hopefully that gets added in. Perhaps as something in your hideout if you've unlocked Zana.

Comment: Even a chat command similar to /passives would be better than nothing.